# Different models always the same loss

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, lstm

I am trying to predict a time series using LSTM. My problem is that no matter how complex my network is, how many layers I use, what the batch size is, dropout, the number of time steps, the loss always ends up being the same value.

I haven't found anything regarding this topic. What could be the problem?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried non neural network models for comparison? Maybe it's the best you can get?

Comment: if the loss is the same, are the predictions exactly the same too?

Comment: No, the predictions are not the same. They have different rmse. I compare the results to the persistence model. I could beat the model if I used 1000 data points and a single layer network. However, when I try to predict all the data points, I can not beat the baseline model.